# Rare characters when concatenating files with "ñ" or accents with PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have a script that concatenates all the txt files in the current directory but when there are Spanish characters in one of the files ("ñ", accents) the output shows rare characters.
I have tried several options but none of them work.

On my machine I have this configuration

```
[System.Text.Encoding]::Default.EncodingName
Europeo occidental (Windows)
```

This is my code:

```
Write-Host "Pagina Codigos" -ForegroundColor 'yellow'
[System.Text.Encoding]::Default.EncodingName

$PSDefaultParameterValues['Out-File:Encoding'] = 'utf8'

$dir_A_Concatenar = $args[0]
$dir_A_Concatenar = ".\*.txt"

$ficResultado = Split-Path (Split-Path $dir_A_Concatenar -Parent) -Leaf

foreach ($item in Get-ChildItem $dir_A_Concatenar) {
    " " >> ".\$ficResultado.sal"        
    $s="------------------- INICIO : $item --------------------------------------------------------"
    $s >> ".\$ficResultado.sal"

    " " >> ".\$ficResultado.sal"

    Write-Host "Start Processing $item" -ForegroundColor 'green'

    cat $item | Select-Object -Skip 0 | Out-File -Append .\$ficResultado.sal              
    (Get-Content $item) | Set-Content -Encoding UTF8 -Path ".\gc_sc_encodeutf8.sal"        

    Get-Content $item | Add-Content ".\gc_ac.sal"
    Get-Content $item | Out-File ".\gc_ofenc_utf8.sal" -Encoding UTF8 -Append

    cat $item | sc -Encoding UTF8 .\CATsc_encodeUTF8.sal

    Write-Host $item

    " " >> ".\$ficResultado.sal"
    $s="------------------- FINAL : $item --------------------------------------------------------"
    $s >> ".\$ficResultado.sal"
    " " >> ".\$ficResultado.sal"

    Write-Host "Ended Processing $item" -ForegroundColor 'white'
}
```

As you can see I have tried several ways to concatenate but they all give me the same result.

Comment: Did you try `Get-Content $item -Encoding Default` or `Get-Content $item -Encoding OEM`?

Comment: Perfect with Default, if I use OEM it doesn't works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the encoding `Default` when importing your data:

```
Get-Content $item -Encoding Default | ...
```